# Emacs lisp escaping regexp

Tags: regex, emacs, escaping, lisp

As a first experience in defining a function for emacs, I would like to make write a function that take all occurences of argv[some number] and renumber them in order.

This is done inside emacs with replace-regexp, entering as search/replace strings

```
argv\[\([0-9]+\)\]
argv[\,(+ 1 \#)]
```

Now, I want to write this in my .emacs so I understand I need to escape also for Lisp special characters. So in my opinion it should write

```
(defun argv-order () 
  (interactive)
  (goto-char 1)
  (replace-regexp "argv\\[[0-9]+\\]" "argv[\\,\(+ 1 \\#\)]")
)
```

The search string works fine but the replacement string gives me the error "invalid use of \ in replacement text. I've been trying around adding or removing some \ but with no success.

Any idea ?

Comment: The amount of backslashes in string should be double of that for interactive use. That's it.

Comment: This is not enough because you have to escape the parentheses that are a special character in List but not in regexp.

Comment: It's enough. Interactively, you put `\(\)` if you want to capture.
In elisp you put `\\(\\)` in the same place. If you want plain
parens, you don't have to escape them in both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the help from `replace-regexp` (the bold is mine):

*In **interactive** calls, the replacement text may contain `\,'*

You are not using it interactively in your defun, hence the error message.  Another quote from the same help that helps solving your problem:

```
This function is usually the wrong thing to use in a Lisp program.
What you probably want is a loop like this:
  (while (re-search-forward REGEXP nil t)
    (replace-match TO-STRING nil nil))
which will run faster and will not set the mark or print anything.
```

And a solution based on that:

```
(defun argv-order ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((count 0))
    (while (re-search-forward "argv\\[[0-9]+\\]" nil t)
      (replace-match (format "argv[%d]" count) nil nil)
      (setq count (1+ count)))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this work perfectly! I thought putting (interactive) would have been enough for my solution, but I missed that help page ...